# C++ permutation tree

Tags: c++, tree, permutation

I have tasks and I want to calculate the most profitable order to arrange them.

Instead of checking every permutation and doing n*n! calculations, I want to build a tree of permutations, that is, the number of children at each level decreases by 1, and at each node the sub-permutation that has already been calculated will be saved and not recalculated.

For example, if I have 4 tasks, the tree will look like this:

[image: tree example]

My attached code is missing. I don't know how to build the tree and the give nodes the indexes as in the figure. I know how to deal with a binary tree, but not with a tree where the number of children is different at each lavel.

(The value of each task depends on its location.
I know how to do that, so I didn't include it in the question).

```
int n = 4;

struct node
{
    int task_index = -1;
    double value;
    struct node **next;
};

void build_tree(node *current_node, int current_level = 0)
{
    if (current_level < 1 || current_level >= n)
        return;

    // current_node->task_index = ? ;
    current_node->next = new node *[n - current_level];

    for (int i = 0; i < n - current_level; i++)
    {
        build_tree(current_node->next[i], current_level + 1);
    }
}

void print_tree(node *current_node, int current_level = 0)
{
    // print indexes
}

void delete_tree(node *current_node, int current_level = 0)
{
    // delete nodes
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root = new node;
    build_tree(root);
    print_tree(root);
    delete_tree(root);
    delete root;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ".... but I wanted to reduce the code" you do not need to include any header for this code

Comment: "My attached code is wrong." you need to explain what is wrong and post a [mcve]

Comment: `delete[] root;` is undefined. You need to `delete` what has been allocated via `new`. `delete[]` is for `new[]`

Comment: Thanks @463035818_is_not_a_number, I fixed it according to your comments.

Comment: What is wrong about the code? What does it do, what should it do instead? "My attached code is missing" ?!? Please read about [mcve]

Comment: "I don't know how to build the tree and the give nodes the indexes as in the figure" mean I want the code to build a tree like in the figure...

Comment: and what does it do? When I run this code nothing happens, no output.

Comment: Your design is overly complicated for what you want to accomplish. If you have an oracle that tells you for a given permutation how well it would do, simply iterate over all permutations and apply your oracle. Keep track of only the best you encountered. You don't need to keep the entire search tree in memory for that.

Comment: @bitmask If that function works by iterating over the values of the permutation in order and doing some nontrivial calculation, then saving that partial progress in the tree nodes is likely an optimization.  Of course you could optimize further using a stack and throwing out the cached results once you're done with them, but using the tree means you can go back and inspect the whole process after the fact, which could be desirable.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I have no problem just entering data and displaying, but I think the tree itself is not built according to the figure. I want to build the tree and then insert the data into it as in the figure.

Comment: @bitmask, Of course there isn't such an oracle. I have to try all the permutations, but using the permutation tree I thought to reduce sub-permutations that I have already tried, and not calculate them again. That is to optimize. It is true that this solution is limited if there will be a lot of tasks, but it is still possible to solve with optimization more tasks than without.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, Thanks! you wrote exactly what I meant.

Comment: apart from `root` you never actually create a `node`

Comment: @יצחקשליסל What you describe, then, is not a tree, but a DAG. In your provided code, you don't build one of those. And even then, using a backtracking-stack is probably better suited. P.S.: An oracle in TCS is just an opaque-box function.

Answer (score 1):

```
void build_tree(node *current_node, int current_level = 0)
{
    if (current_level < 1 || current_level >= n)
        return;

    // current_node->task_index = ? ;
    current_node->next = new node *[n - current_level];

    for (int i = 0; i < n - current_level; i++)
    {
        build_tree(current_node->next[i], current_level + 1);
    }
}
```

When called with the default parameter of `current_level = 0`, as you illustrate in your code below, this function exits on the first line without doing anything.  You need to decide whether you are indexing starting from 0 or from 1.

Other than that, the general outline of the algorithm looks okay, although I did not explicitly check for correctness.

Now, more broadly: is this an exercise to see if you can write a tree structure, or are you trying to get the job done?  In the latter case you probably want to use a prebuilt data structure like that in the boost graph library.

If it's an exercise in building a tree structure, is it specifically an exercise to see if you can write code dealing with raw pointers-to-pointers?  If not, you should work with the correct C++ containers for the job.  For instance you probably want to store the list of child nodes in a `std::vector` rather than have a pointer-to-pointer with the only way to tell how many child nodes exist being the depth of the node in the tree.  (There may be *some* use case for such an extremely specialized structure if you are hyper-optimizing something for a very specific reason, but it doesn't look like that's what's going on here.)

Comment: The indexes can start from 0, then they will be 0, 1, 2 and not as I drew 1, 2, 3. But then, it is better to initialize the root value at -1 so it be clear that it is not one of the indexes.

The goal is to find the optimal arrangement of the tasks. For this, all the permutations must be calculated, but I thought to optimize and "remember" sub-permutations that have already been calculated, so as not to recalculate them, i.e. perform "dynamic programming".

Comment: This is not a graphical or a tree exercise. The goal is to find the optimal arrangement. At each node, besides the index, additional values will also enter, but my problem is in the construction of the tree and not in the calculation of the values.

It is not necessary to do it using tree. I thought that using tree would be that simple.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive way to generate permutations is if you have *n* items then all of the permutations of the items are each of the *n* items concatenated with the permutations of the *n*-1 remaining items. In code this is easier to do if you pass around the collection of items.

Below I do it with an `std::vector<int>`. Once using a vector it makes more sense to just follow the "rule of zero" pattern and let the nodes have vectors of children and then not need to dynamically allocate anything manually:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int task_index = -1;
    double value;
    std::vector<node> next;
};

std::vector<int> remove_item(int item, const std::vector<int>& items) {
    std::vector<int> output(items.size() - 1);
    std::copy_if(items.begin(), items.end(), output.begin(),
        [item](auto v) {return v != item; }
    );
    return output;
}

void build_tree(node& current_node, const std::vector<int>& tasks)
{
    auto n = static_cast<int>(tasks.size());
    for (auto curr_task : tasks) {
        node child{ curr_task, 0.0, {} };
        if (n > 1) {
            build_tree(child, remove_item(curr_task, tasks));
        }
        current_node.next.emplace_back(std::move(child));
    }
}

void print_tree(const node& current_node)
{
    std::cout << "( " << current_node.task_index << " ";
    for (const auto& child : current_node.next) {
        print_tree(child);
    }
    std::cout << " )";
}

int main()
{
    node root{ -1, 0.0, {} };
    build_tree(root, { 1, 2, 3 });
    print_tree(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your explanation what you are trying to build is a data structure that reuses sub-trees for common permutations:

```
012 -> X
210 -> X
```

such that `X` is only instantiated once. This, of course, is recursive, seeing as

```
01 -> Y
10 -> Y
Y2 -> X
```

If you look at it closely, there are 2^n such subtrees, because any prefix can have any one of the n input tasks used or not. This means you can represent the subtree as an index into an array of size 2^n, with a total footprint O(n*2^n), which improves on the vastly larger >n! tree:

```
struct Edge {
  std::size_t task;
  std::size_t sub;
};
struct Node {
  std::vector<Edge> successor; // size in [0,n]
};
std::vector<Node> permutations; // size exactly 2^n
```

This will have this structure:

```
permutations: 0 1 2 3 4 ...
              |-^
              |---^
              |-------^
                |---^
                  |-^
```

Where the node at, e.g., location 3 has both task 0 and 1 already used and "points" to all (n-2) subtrees.

---

Of course, building this is not entirely trivial, but it compressed the search space and allows you re-use results for specific sub-trees.

You can build the table like this:

```
permutations.resize(1<<n);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size(permutations); ++i) {
    permutations[i].successor.reserve(n); // maybe better heuristic?
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        if (((1<<j) & i) == 0) {
            permutations[i].successor.push_back({j,(1<<j)|i});
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is a live demo for n=4.](https://godbolt.org/z/aYaY6cc3a)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

I'm not sure I understood everything, but I didn't mean that that:
[0,1,2] -> X
[2,1,0] -> X
because they are different.

Just to be sure, let's say there are 5 tasks, and let's say you've already calculated all the sub-permutations of 2 tasks, among them, this sub-promotion:
[2, 3]

So when you come to calculate the following sub-permutations:
[2, 3], 0
[2, 3], 1
[2, 3], 4

You will be able to use the [2, 3] you have already calculated, so you will only have to calculate 3 tasks orers instead of starting to recalculate 9 tasks orders.

Comment: @יצחקשליסל The assumption is that if you have a permutation p = ZY, you have a way to compute the cost function c(p) from c(Y), without c(Y) depending on Z. That would mean that you can choose the best Y for each p = ZY without considering Z. This fits neatly with the way the permuatations vector is structured. Assign each cell Y in the vector the partial cost function c(Y). Then proceed recursively by decomposing Z=Az and assign c(zY), then decompose A, and so forth.